# Use mailchimp as a listserv?

Tags: email, mailing-list, mailchimp

I am looking for a free listserv service for a group of around 100 - 200 members. I just found mailchimp, which seems to be good for sending a newsletter to the group, but is it possible to configure mailchimp to let subscribers reply to everyone in the group?

I am looking for code-free solution.

Comment: I have the same question, except my list contains about 2,000 people. I know there's a way that [email or form submissions can post to a blog](https://en.support.wordpress.com/post-by-email/), and I know I can use an [RSS campaign in MailChimp](https://mailchimp.com/features/rss-to-email/) to scrape posts from the blog and send to the list. But I want this blog to be private (not just obscure). I'm not sure if MailChimp's RSS mechanism requires the blog to be public. I'm reaching out to [MailChimp](https://twitter.com/MailChimp) on Twitter...we'll see what develops.

Comment: I have the same question. I’m guessing the answer is ‘no’ since this SE question was ranked higher than any help page on Mailchimp on how to do it.